# How each Compose dependency affects the Compose project

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Jetpack Compose [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose) says there are 7 dependencies:

```
compose.animation
compose.compiler
compose.foundation
compose.material
compose.material3
compose.runtime
compose.ui
```

But I can use all Composable and animation functions of Compose without adding dependencies of `compose.animation` and `compose.foundation` among them. I added the dependencies like this:

```kotlin
val compose = listOf(
    "androidx.compose.ui:ui:${Versions.Compose.Master}",
    "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:${Versions.Compose.Master}",
    "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:${Versions.Compose.Master}",
    "androidx.compose.material:material:${Versions.Compose.Master}",
    "androidx.activity:activity-compose:${Versions.Compose.Activity}",
    "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:${Versions.Compose.Master}",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:${Versions.Compose.Lifecycle}"
)
```

Is there any benefit to the project by adding all Compose dependencies?

Comment: Some of your existing dependencies are depend on animation and foundation underneath, so there's no need to add them explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jetpack compose level：

```
material(Button,Text,...) -> foundation(Column,Image,...) -> animation(Animatable,animateXXAsState,...) -> ui(Alignment,Modifier,...) -> runtime(remember,State,...)
```

Therefore, the content of the advanced package you refer to will contain subordinate content. For example, the material you refer to will contain foundation, animation, UI and runtime, so you only need to refer to the material, if your project does not intend to use the material style, you only need to import the foundation

compose compiler layer is actually kotlin compiler plugin,You don't need to introduce dependencies

```
  composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
    }
```

please try

```
val compose = listOf(
    "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:${Versions.Compose.Master}",
    "androidx.compose.material:material:${Versions.Compose.Master}",
    "androidx.activity:activity-compose:${Versions.Compose.Activity}",
    "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:${Versions.Compose.Master}",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:${Versions.Compose.Lifecycle}"
)
composeOptions {
            kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
            kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
        }
```